# Django-taggit migration fails at AlterUniqueTogether

Tags: django, django-taggit

I'm trying to migrate my Django application which uses jazzband django-taggit
The error I get is:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "taggit_taggeditem_content_type_id_object_i_4bb97a8e_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id, object_id, tag_id)=(41, 596, 242) is duplicated.
```

The migration in question reads:

```
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name="taggeditem", unique_together={("content_type", "object_id", "tag")}
        )
```

https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit/blob/master/taggit/migrations/0003_taggeditem_add_unique_index.py#L12-L14

Which translates to the following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE "taggit_taggeditem" ADD CONSTRAINT "taggit_taggeditem_content_type_id_object_i_4bb97a8e_uniq" UNIQUE ("content_type_id", "object_id", "tag_id");
COMMIT;
```

Checking the table in question I do get:

```
# SELECT * FROM public.taggit_taggeditem WHERE tag_id=242 ORDER BY object_id;
  id  | tag_id | object_id | content_type_id 
------+--------+-----------+-----------------
  691 |    242 |       356 |              41
 2904 |    242 |       356 |              41
  680 |    242 |       486 |              41
 2893 |    242 |       486 |              41
  683 |    242 |       596 |              41
 2896 |    242 |       596 |              41
```

What is the suggested way to resolve the `django.db.utils.IntegrityError` error and successfully finish the migration? I think the same will happen with object_id 486 and 356 (+ several more).

Comment: You should first filter out the duplicates.

Comment: So for example I would only keep id 691 and delete 2904 as both have same tag_id, object_id and content_type_id, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before migrating the model, you should make a [*data migration*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). You thus probably better first remove the migration file, then make a data migration with:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations --empty app_name
```

In this migration could look like:

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

def remove_duplicates(apps, schema_editor):
    Model = apps.get_model('app_name', 'ModelName')
    Model.objects.annotate(
        has_dup=Exists(
            Model.objects.filter(
                pk__lt=OuterRef('pk'),
                content_type_id=OuterRef('content_type_id'),
                object_id=OuterRef('object_id'),
                tag_id=OuterRef('tag_id'),
            )
        )
    ).filter(has_dup=True).delete()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', '1234_some_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(remove_duplicates),
    ]
```

Where you replace *`app_name`* and *`ModelName`* with the name of the app and the model respectively (and check that it depends on the previous migration file).

Here we thus look for `Model`s that contain duplicate data with a primary key less than the current one. We delete such records.

Next you make the migrations for the app again:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

I would (strongly) advise to backup the database first before running this, since it is always possible that there is a sophisticated problem with the data migration.